# Properly closing asyncio.ClientSession before cancelling the future

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a list of tasks that I am awaiting and the fastest response will be saved and rest will be cancelled

```
done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
    futures, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)

print(done.pop().result())

for future in pending:
    future.cancel()
```

Each of these futures has this

```
session = asyncio.CreateSession()
# some code to request
# some code to process response
await session.close()
```

When I cancel the other futures, I get a warning

```
Unclosed client session client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x10f95c6d8>
```

What is the best way to close this open session before cancelling the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
for future in pending:
    future.cancel()
```

If you want to cancel something you should not only call `cancel()` method but also await task actually cancelled:

```
from contextlib import suppress

for task in pending:
    task.cancel()
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await task
```

Please [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810272/1113207) to see how cancellation works.

2)

```
session = asyncio.CreateSession()
# some code to request
# some code to process response
await session.close()
```

And somewhere between this lines `CancelledError` (or other exception) can be raised. If it'll happen line `await session.close()` would never be reached.

Everywhere in Python if you take some resources and would need to free it later you should always wrap all your code between taking/freeing to try/finally block:

```
session = asyncio.CreateSession()
try:
    # some code to request
    # some code to process response
finally:
    await session.close()
```

Again, it's common pattern related [not only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770375/1113207) to asyncio.

Comment: I came across the 'with' syntax. Your explanation is basically what 'with' does. Am I correct?

Comment: @Abhinav_A yes, that's what `with` syntax does in current case (and usually in many other cases). Even better here would be to use newer `async with` syntax (see first code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172471/1113207) for example).