# Set max concurrency with asyncio.create_subprocess_exec

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, subprocess, python-asyncio

I need to run a program about 500 times with different inputs.
I'd like to use `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` and want to limit the number of processes running at the same time so as not to clog up the machine. 
Is there a way to set the concurrency level? For example, I'd expect something like `AbstractEventLoop.set_max_tasks`.

Comment: Use `asyncio.Semaphore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations where one wants to schedule enough program calls that creating each as a coroutine right away starts being an issue, a semaphore-backed task queue as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76661165/1136208) can be useful:

```py
tasks = TaskQueue(NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSES)
for input in MANY_INPUTS:
     await tasks.put(run_program(input))

tasks.join()
```

Answer (score 3):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283102/set-max-concurrency-with-asyncio-create-subprocess-exec/50293509#comment87586906_50283102) by @AndrewSvetlov, you can use an [`asyncio.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) to enforce the limit:

```
async def run_program(input):
    p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(...)
    # ... communicate with the process ...
    p.terminate()
    return something_useful

async def run_throttled(input, sem):
    async with sem:
        result = await run_program(input)
    return result

LIMIT = 10

async def many_programs(inputs):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(LIMIT)
    results = await asyncio.gather(
        *[run_throttled(input, sem) for input in inputs])
    # ...
```