# lock an asyncio function when more than 100 are running?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

This is gonna be a bad explanation but I don't know how else to word this so bear with me please.
I have one function:

```
async def request():
    # this can only be called n times at once
```

But as it says it can only be called n times at once. Is it possible to have some sort of pool with a limited number of objects so I can do this:

```
async def request():
    await with poolOfOneHundred.acquire():
        # do something
```

and then python would acquire 100 of these, and then once it gets to the 101th it would wait at the await with statement until another request() function was finished, then one lock in the pool would be free.

Is this a thing? If not, how could I implement something like this?

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50308812/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48483348/11301900.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore).

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486557/1113207) of how to use it.