# Writing web responses to file in an asyncronous program

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Working on replacing my implementation of a server query tool that uses [`ThreadPoolExecutors`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) with all asynchronous calls using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`. Most of the transition is straight forward since network calls are non-blocking IO, it's the saving of the responses that has me in a conundrum.

All the examples I am using, even the docs for both libraries, use `asyncio.gather()` which collects all the awaitable results. In my case, these results can be files in the many GB range, and I don't want to store them in memory.

Whats an appropriate way to solve this? Is it to use [`asyncio.as_completed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) and then:

```
for f in as_completed(aws):
    earliest_result = await f
    # Assumes `loop` defined under `if __name__` block outside coroutine
    loop = get_event_loop()
    # Run the blocking IO in an exectuor and write to file
    _ = await loop.run_in_executor(None, save_result, earliest_result)
```

Doesn't this introduce a thread (assuming I use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` by default) thus making this an asynchronous, multi-threaded program vice an asynchronous, single-threaded program?

Futher, does this ensure only 1 `earliest_result` is being written to file at any time? I dont want the call to `await loop.run_in_executor(...)` to be running, then another result comes in and I try to run to the same file; I could limit with a semaphore I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest  to make use of aiohttp [Streaming API](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/streams.html#). Write your responses directly to the disk instead of RAM and return file names instead of responses itself from gather. Doing so won't use a lot of memory at all. This is a small demo of what I mean:

```
import asyncio

import aiofiles
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def make_request(session, url):
    response = await session.request(method="GET", url=url)
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    async for data in response.content.iter_chunked(1024):
        async with aiofiles.open(filename, "ba") as f:
            await f.write(data)
    return filename


async def main():
    urls = ['https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles',
            'https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp']
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        coros = [make_request(session, url) for url in urls]
        result_files = await asyncio.gather(*coros)
    print(result_files)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 3):

Very clever way of using the `asyncio.gather` method by @merrydeath.
I tweaked the helper function like below and got a big performance boost:

```
    response = await session.get(url)
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    async with aiofiles.open(filename, "ba") as f:
        await f.write(response.read())
```

Results may differ depending on the download connection speed.

Answer (score 0):

> In my case, these results can be files in the many GB range, and I don't want to store them in memory.

If I'm correct and in your code single `aws` means a downloading of a single file, you may face a following problem: while `as_completed` allows to swap data from RAM to HDD asap, all your `aws` running parallely storing each their data (buffer with partly downloaded file) in RAM simultaneously.

To avoid this you'll need to use semaphore to ensure not to much files are downloading parallely in the first place thus to prevent RAM overuse.

Here's example of using [semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486557/1113207).

> Doesn't this introduce a thread (assuming I use a ThreadPoolExecutor
>   by default) thus making this an asynchronous, multi-threaded program
>   vice an asynchronous, single-threaded program?

I'm not sure, I understand your question, but yes, your code will use threads, but only `save_result` will be executed inside those threads. All other code still runs in single main thread. Nothing bad here.

> Futher, does this ensure only 1 earliest_result is being written to
>   file at any time?

Yes, it is[*]. To be precisely keyword `await` at last line of your snippet will ensure it:

```
_ = await loop.run_in_executor(None, save_result, earliest_result)
```

You can read it as: "Start executing `run_in_executor` asynchronously and suspend execution flow at this line until `run_in_executor` is done and returned result".

---

[*] Yes, if you don't run multiple for `f in as_completed(aws)` loops parallely in the first place.