# asyncio.Semaphore RuntimeError: Task got Future attached to a different loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, semaphore, python-asyncio

When I run this code in Python 3.7:

```
import asyncio

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)

async def work():
    async with sem:
        print('working')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(work(), work(), work())

asyncio.run(main())
```

It fails with RuntimeError:

```
$ python3 demo.py
working
working
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 13, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "demo.py", line 11, in main
    await asyncio.gather(work(), work(), work())
  File "demo.py", line 6, in work
    async with sem:
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/locks.py", line 92, in __aenter__
    await self.acquire()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/locks.py", line 474, in acquire
    await fut
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<work() running at demo.py:6> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py:664]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### Python 3.10+:

This error message should not occur anymore, see answer from @mmdanziger:

> (...) the implementation of Semaphore has been changed and no longer grabs the current loop on init

#### Python 3.9 and older:

It's because Semaphore constructor sets its `_loop` attribute – in [asyncio/locks.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3bbcc92577f8e616bc94c679040043bacd00ebf1/Lib/asyncio/locks.py):

```
class Semaphore(_ContextManagerMixin):

    def __init__(self, value=1, *, loop=None):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Semaphore initial value must be >= 0")
        self._value = value
        self._waiters = collections.deque()
        if loop is not None:
            self._loop = loop
        else:
            self._loop = events.get_event_loop()
```

But `asyncio.run()` starts a completely new loop – in [asyncio/runners.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3bbcc92577f8e616bc94c679040043bacd00ebf1/Lib/asyncio/runners.py), it's also metioned in the documentation:

```
def run(main, *, debug=False):
    if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")

    if not coroutines.iscoroutine(main):
        raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))

    loop = events.new_event_loop()
    ...
```

`Semaphore` initiated outside of `asyncio.run()` grabs the asyncio "default" loop and so cannot be used with the event loop created with `asyncio.run()`.

#### Solution

Initiate `Semaphore` from code called by `asyncio.run()`. You will have to pass them to the right place, there are more possibilities how to do that, you can for example use [contextvars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html), but I will just give the simplest example:

```
import asyncio

async def work(sem):
    async with sem:
        print('working')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
    await asyncio.gather(work(sem), work(sem), work(sem))

asyncio.run(main())
```

The same issue (and solution) is probably also with `asyncio.Lock`, `asyncio.Event`, and `asyncio.Condition`.

Comment: Oh. I came across the same problem. Thanks for the answer:)

Comment: Would you mind adding words for `asyncio.Lock, .Event, .Condition`, for the sake of searches? They appear to have the same mechanism. - I tested it for Lock and it definitely applies.

Comment: This is great explanation. And thanks a lot for the straightforward example! :)

Comment: It also applies for .Event, to save anybody 4 hours of investigating

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As of Python 3.10 OP's code will run as written. This is because the implementation of `Semaphore` has been changed and no longer grabs the current loop on init. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73601546/837451) for more discussion.

Python 3.10 implementation from [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eace09e63ed7978dbdfeb1ae537fac505e6b5b0e/Lib/asyncio/locks.py#L348)

```py
class Semaphore(_ContextManagerMixin, mixins._LoopBoundMixin):
    """A Semaphore implementation.
    A semaphore manages an internal counter which is decremented by each
    acquire() call and incremented by each release() call. The counter
    can never go below zero; when acquire() finds that it is zero, it blocks,
    waiting until some other thread calls release().
    Semaphores also support the context management protocol.
    The optional argument gives the initial value for the internal
    counter; it defaults to 1. If the value given is less than 0,
    ValueError is raised.
    """

    def __init__(self, value=1, *, loop=mixins._marker):
        super().__init__(loop=loop)
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Semaphore initial value must be >= 0")
        self._value = value
        self._waiters = collections.deque()
        self._wakeup_scheduled = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution for Python 3.9 and older is to instantiate the Event, Lock, Semaphore, etc. as a first step inside the main() task, where possible.

I validated this with an Event case tested on Python 3.10 (Windows) vs Python 3.9 (Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).