# Why am I getting an ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I load into the `proxies` variable my proxies and try to do async requests for get ip. Its simple:

```py
async def get_ip(proxy):
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(connect=5)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:
        try:
            async with session.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', proxy=proxy, timeout=timeout) as response:
                json_response = await response.json()
                print(json_response)
        except:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    proxies = []

    start_time = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get_ip(proxy)) for proxy in proxies]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    print('time spent to work: {} sec --------------'.format(time.time()-start_time))
```

This code work fine when i try to do 100-200-300-400 requests, but when is count more than 500 i alltime getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "async_get_ip.py", line 60, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 571, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 539, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1739, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\selectors.py", line 323, in select
    r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\selectors.py", line 314, in _select
    r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()
```

I was looking for a solution, but all I found was a limitation at the OS. Can I somehow get around this problem without using additional libraries?

Comment: Since it appears you're using Windows, try switching to the [proactor event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.ProactorEventLoop) which doesn't use select().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to start unlimited amount of requests simultaneously. Each started request will consume some resources from CPU/RAM to OS's select() capacity, what, as is in your case, sooner or later will lead to problems.

To avoid the situation you should use [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) which allows to limit maximum amount of simultaneous connections.

I believe only few changes should be made in your code:

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(50)

async def get_ip(proxy):
    async with sem:
        # ...
```

[Here's full complex example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486557/1113207) of how to use semaphore in general.

---

**P.S.**

```
except:
    pass
```

You should never do such thing, it'll just [break a code sooner or later](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327/1113207).

At very-very least use `except Exception`.

Comment: wow thank you. Can you please explain me what difference between ```except``` and ```except Exception```? Or you mean something like ```except ValueError```?

Comment: @kshnkvn `except:` will catch [every kind of exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) including "service exceptions" like `GeneratorExit` or `SystemExit` non of which is subclass of `Exception` thus it can break work of generators or shutdown process. `except Exception` will catch only "error exceptions", which in 99% of cases is what you really want to achieve.