# Why we need asyncio synchronization primitives, when to use these?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

According to [asyncio synchronization primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#synchronization-primitives), there are synchronization
methods.

- I am getting confused about why we need synchronization in asyncio?
- I mean, asyncio is
  asynchronous.
- Is it meaningful to add something synchronous in asynchronization?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Synchronization primitives don't make your code synchronous, they make coroutines in your code synchronized.

Few examples:

- You may want to start/continue some coroutine only when another coroutine allows it (`asyncio.Event`)
- You may want some part of your code to be executed only by single coroutine at the same time and other to wait for their turn (`asyncio.Lock`)
- You may want some part of your code to be executed only by limited number on coroutines at the same time (`asyncio.Semaphore`)

Take a look at a [practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48483348/1113207) of using `asyncio.Semaphore`.