# How to call async func in a sync func?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
async def func1():
    print(f'{datetime.now().time()} func1 start')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'{datetime.now().time()} func1 over')


async def func21():
    print(f'{datetime.now().time()} func21 start')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'{datetime.now().time()} func21 over')


def func2():
    print(f'{datetime.now().time()} func2 start')
    time.sleep(1)

    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(func21(), asyncio.get_event_loop())
    print(f'{datetime.now().time()} func2 over')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(3):
        func2()
        asyncio.run(func1())
```

As seen, I want to call async func21() in sync func2(), but it produces RuntimeError when running.
So is it possible to do `call async func21() in sync func2()`?If yes, so how would that be?

Comment: In many cases, what you are asking for can be done by running an event loop in a secondary thread and executing the async function there.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231451/wrapping-python-async-for-synchronous-execution/70254610#70254610

Answer (score 0):

You can't run async function inside sync function (unless you run the whole event loop there). It's the [intentional design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218758/1113207), because it's important to know where the code can return control to an event loop to avoid concurrency problems.