# Call an async function from a sync function called by an async function

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have this configuration

```py
async def A():
    B()

async def C():
    # do stuff

def B():
    # do stuff
    r = C()
    # want to call C() with the same loop and store the result

asyncio.run(A())
```

I don't really know how to do that. I tried this by reading some solutions on the web:

```py
def B():
    task = asyncio.create_task(C())
    asyncio.wait_for(task, timeout=30)
    result = task.result()
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Why do not make the `B` async and `await` it in `A`? In that case, you could be able to invoke `r = await C()` in `B`.

Comment: Because B() is actually called by both async and non-async functions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231451/wrapping-python-async-for-synchronous-execution/70254610#70254610.  The idea is to start a second thread that runs the coroutine C() and returns the result.  Then instead of simply calling C() in your function B(), you do `r = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(C(), loop).result()`.

Comment: Does `B` actually need to *access* the result or just return it?

Answer (score 0):

Since asyncio does not allow its event loop to be nested, you can use **nest_async** library to allow nested use of `asyncio.run` and `asyncio.run_until_complete` methods in the current event loop or a new one:

First, install the library:

```
pip install nest-asyncio
```

Then, add the following to the beginning of your script:

```py
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()
```

And the rest of the code:

```py
async def A():
    B()

async def C():
    # do stuff

def B():
    # do stuff
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(C())
    # want to call C() with the same loop and store the result

asyncio.run(A())
```

Comment: No I can't, I get the error "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running". Since asyncio doesn't support nested loop

Comment: @graille Is it necessary to be in the current running loop? What if you could run it in a new event loop?

Comment: You cannot launch a new loop when a loop is already running: "RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running"