# Python aioredis "await wasn't used with future" error

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aioredis

I have some problem with async functions, here is my code:

```
def get_redis_connection(connection_string: str):
    hostport, *options = connection_string.split(",")
    host, _, port = hostport.partition(":")
    redis_retry = Retry(ExponentialBackoff(), 5)
    arguments = {
        "retry": redis_retry,
        "retry_on_error": [BusyLoadingError, ConnectionError, TimeoutError],
    }
    for option in options:
        opt: str
        value: Union[int, str]
        opt, _, value = option.partition("=")
        if opt == "port":
            value = int(value)
        elif opt == "ssl":
            value = value.lower() == "true"
        elif opt == "abortConnect":
            continue
        arguments[opt] = value

    return Redis(host, int(port), **arguments)


async def get_async_redis_connection(connection_string: str):
    hostport, *options = connection_string.split(",")
    host, _, port = hostport.partition(":")
    _, _, password = options[0].partition("=")
    redis_url = f'rediss://:{password}@{host}:{port}'
    pool = aioredis.ConnectionPool.from_url(redis_url)
    return aioredis.Redis(connection_pool=pool, ssl=True)


def put_redis_data(redis_connection, hash, hash_name, payload):
    ttl = int(os.environ.get("TTL", 12))
    redis_connection.hset(hash_key, hash_name, json.dumps(payload))
    redis_connection.expire(hash_key, timedelta(hours=ttl))
```

```
class Worker():
    
    def __init__(self, azure_connection_string: str, redis_connection_string: str):
        super().__init__()
        self._redis_connection = get_redis_connection(redis_connection_string)
        self._redis_async_connection = asyncio.run(get_async_redis_connection(redis_connection_string))
        self._connection_string = azure_connection_string
        

class MyFirstWorker(Worker):

    def __init__(self, azure_connection_string: str, redis_connection_string: str):
        super().__init__(azure_connection_string, redis_connection_string)

    async def async_get_redis_data(self, key, opt):
        async with self._redis_async_connection.client() as redis:
            windows = await redis.hget(key, "windows")
            doors = await redis.hget(key, "doors")
        return windows, doors

    def _process(self, opt):
        key = str(os.getenv("KEY"))
        windows, doors = asyncio.run(self.async_get_redis_data(key, opt))
        matching_dataclass = MatchingPayload(json.loads(windows)["PayloadFields"])
        logger.info(f"Matching completed")
        put_redis_data(
            self._redis_connection, key, "match:results", matching_dataclass
        )
```

I have similar workers in separate threads (like MyFirstWorker, MySecondWorker, MyThirdWorker), one of them has an async redis data getter (`async def async_get_redis_data(self, key, opt)`) other operations with redis are performed synchronously throughout the project.

Here's the error I get:

```
RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
```

I understand that the problem is due to the way I use aioredis, it is important for me to keep the _process method sync, but still perform the redis.hget operations async
Please help me understand how to fix this error?

I thought it was because of this line:

```
windows, doors = asyncio.run(self.async_get_redis_data(key, opt))
```

I tried replacing it with

```
windows, doors = await self.async_get_redis_data(key, opt)
```

But in this case, I get another error related to the fact that the _process method is synchronous (TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable coroutine object), but it should remain so.

Here is full traceback messages for my error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
           │    │                  └ <coroutine object FirstWorker.async_get_redis_data at 0x7f5acc1893c0>
           │    └ <function BaseEventLoop.run_until_complete at 0x7f5ae568e550>
           └ <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=True debug=False>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           │      └ <method 'result' of '_asyncio.Task' objects>
           └ <Task finished name='Task-109' coro=<FirstWorker.async_get_redis_data() done, defined at /app/workers/matching_worker.py:2...

  File "/app/workers/first_worker.py", line 22, in async_get_redis_data
    windows = await redis.hget(key, "windows")
                       │     │    │    └ {'Action': 29, 'service': 0, 'ObjectType': 0, 'ObjectId': 'e8742fds-9b49-4cff-adaf-f4rg542d7da079', 'TaskId': 'c73605fb-403a-41...
                       │     │    └ 'e8742fds-9b49-4cff-adaf-f4rg542d7da079_c73605fb-403a-41cc-9c0a-a32f4c81f2f4_a9d8b4e0-fca9-e982-00f1-3c05c2cc207d'
                       │     └ <function Redis.hget at 0x7f5afs52160>
                       └ <unprintable Redis object>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aioredis/client.py", line 1085, in execute_command
    return await self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
                 │    │              │     │               └ {}
                 │    │              │     └ 'HGET'
                 │    │              └ SSLConnection<host=my-host.com,port=6380,db=0>
                 │    └ <function Redis.parse_response at 0x7f5ges6bd310>
                 └ <unprintable Redis object>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aioredis/client.py", line 1101, in parse_response
    response = await connection.read_response()
                     │          └ <function Connection.read_response at 0x7f5acf7ab1f0>
                     └ SSLConnection<host=my-host.com,port=6380,db=0>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 910, in read_response
    await self.disconnect()
          │    └ <function Connection.disconnect at 0x7f5acf4e50>
          └ SSLConnection<host=my-host.com,port=6380,db=0>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 806, in disconnect
    await self._writer.wait_closed()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
          │    └ <member '_writer' of 'Connection' objects>
          └ SSLConnection<host=my-host.com,port=6380,db=0>

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 359, in wait_closed
    await self._protocol._get_close_waiter(self)
          │    │         │                 └ <StreamWriter transport=<asyncio.sslproto._SSLProtocolTransport object at 0x7f5bnn56772e0> reader=<StreamReader transport=<asy...
          │    │         └ <function StreamReaderProtocol._get_close_waiter at 0x7f5ae5696ca0>
          │    └ <asyncio.streams.StreamReaderProtocol object at 0x7f5acc369ac0>
          └ <StreamWriter transport=<asyncio.sslproto._SSLProtocolTransport object at 0x7f5acc3772e0> reader=<StreamReader transport=<asy...

RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
```

Comment: Please share the full traceback messages for your errors. Edit and add them to your question, it can help us troubleshoot.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to run async code within `_process`, which is not an async function.  You can't do this, because such a function has no access to the event loop and so it cannot perform an `await`.  You cannot generally overcome this by calling `asyncio.run` because this function will not work if an event loop is already running.  Can you reorganize your program so that async functions are called within async code?  That's the recommended way to architect an asyncio program, with each thread creating an event loop only once.

Comment: @Cow, I just added full full traceback, hope this helps.

Comment: @PaulCornelius So there is no way to leave the _process method synchronous and add an asynchronous method inside it? The problem is that when I run tests locally, everything works, but when I upload all the code to the kuber, an error appears in real tasks. Perhaps this is because I run tests locally and all my workers work in turn , and after deployment, all workers start working simultaneously.

Comment: You can't run an async function from a sync function.  An async function doesn't return a result immediately - that's the point of it.  It typically cedes control one or more times to an event loop before returning.  So your sync function must wait for the result, but it can't.  Functions declared without the async keyword do not have access to the event loop.  If you're careful you can run async code in another thread and wait on a returned `concurrent.futures.Future.`  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231451/wrapping-python-async-for-synchronous-execution/70254610#70254610