# Semaphore does not limit the number of concurrent executions

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I wrote an asynchronous process in python, using a semaphore to set a limit on the number of concurrent executions-but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
import asyncio

async def gather_with_concurrency(*tasks,limit=3):
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(limit)

    async def sem_task(task):
        async with semaphore:
            return await task
    return await asyncio.gather(*(sem_task(task) for task in tasks))

async def test(second):
    print(f"{second} start")
    await asyncio.sleep(second)
    print(f"{second} done")
    return second

async def _run():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(5):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(test(i+1)))

    return await gather_with_concurrency(*tasks)

def mainloop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(_run())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainloop()
```

The expected output is

```
1 start
2 start
3 start
1 end
4 start
2 end
5 start
3 end
4 end
5 end
```

But the actual output is

```
1 start
2 start
3 start
4 start
5 start
1 done
2 done
3 done
4 done
5 done
```

It looks like all the tasks have been executed at the same time.
Maybe semaphore is not working.
What is the cause of this? How can I make it work correctly?

---

added print after with semaphore.

```py
    async def sem_task(task):
        async with semaphore:
            print("Starting", task)
            return await task
```

Looking at the output, it seems that concurrency is correctly limited. But why does print fire at the same time?

```
1 start
2 start
3 start
4 start
5 start
Starting <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<test() running at stackoverflow.py:16> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fe87b4ab460>()]>>
Starting <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<test() running at stackoverflow.py:16> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fe87b4ab490>()]>>
Starting <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<test() running at stackoverflow.py:16> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fe87b4ab4c0>()]>>
1 done
Starting <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<test() running at stackoverflow.py:16> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fe87b4ab4f0>()]>>
2 done
Starting <Task pending name='Task-6' coro=<test() running at stackoverflow.py:16> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fe87b4ab520>()]>>
3 done
4 done
5 done
```

---

[How to limit concurrency with Python asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483348/how-to-limit-concurrency-with-python-asyncio)

I read this post to implement. Reading the comments, it seems that I needed to pass a coroutine to gather_with_concurrency. The following implementation worked correctly.

```
import asyncio

async def gather_with_concurrency(*cors,limit=3):
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(limit)

    async def sem_task(cor):
        async with semaphore:
            print("Starting", cor)
            return await asyncio.create_task(cor)
    return await asyncio.gather(*(sem_task(cor) for cor in cors))

async def test(second):
    print(f"{second} start")
    await asyncio.sleep(second)
    print(f"{second} done")
    return second

async def _run():
    cors = []
    for i in range(5):
        cors.append(test(i+1))

    return await gather_with_concurrency(*cors)

def mainloop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(_run())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainloop()
```

When create_task is called, does it execute the code before the first await?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `asyncio`, but if you add `print("Starting", task)` as the first thing in the `async with semaphore:` block you can see that the semaphore is working correctly in some way at least. Hopefully that's a helpful data point.

Comment: Thanks Kemp! it seems that concurrency is correctly limited.

Comment: You’re starting the task before passing the unfinished coroutine into `sem_task`. If you want it to not execute at all, you need to pass the task as callable and call it in `sem_task`, at which point it will start.