# How to optimize the below code to read very large multiple file?

Tags: python, optimization

I have folder containing about 5 million files and i have to read the content of each file so that i can form dataframe.It take very long time to do that. Is there any way i can optimize the below code to speed up the process below.

```
new_list = []
file_name=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Folder_5M'):
    for file in files:
        count+=1
        file_name.append(file)
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'rb') as f:
            text = f.read()
            new_list.append(text)
```

Comment: that is an odd task.  First question:  can you just do it once and then save the resultant `new_list` in a pickle or other format?  If so, who cares how long it takes, just run it overnight 1 time and be done with it.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use some OS tool to form a single file and then read this file with python, it'll be significantly faster.

Comment: Do you really need the contents of all 5 million files in memory concurrently?

Comment: yes, i need it to do text preprocessing and perform lsa on it.

Comment: @sudojarvis Why are you opening the files in binary mode if you're doing text processing? Why are you saving the filenames?

Comment: First you need to profile your code to see what takes the most time! If the `append` takes most of the time then counting the amount of files, creating a list of `None` values with the length of the number of files. If the reading takes the longest (which is probably the reason) then `multi threading` is your answer as it is an io bound process.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for how you could use multiprocessing for this.

Constructing a list of files resulting from os.walk is likely to be very fast. It's the processing of those files that's going to take time. With multiprocessing you can do a lot of that work in parallel.

Each process opens the given file, processes it and creates a dataframe. When all of the parallel processing has been carried out you then concatenate the returned dataframes. This last part will be CPU intensive and there's no way (that I can think of) that would allow you to share that load.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, concat
from os import walk
from os.path import join, expanduser
from multiprocessing import Pool

HOME = expanduser('~')

def process(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as data:
            df = DataFrame()
            # analyse your data and populate the dataframe here
            return df
    except Exception:
        return DataFrame()

def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        filenames = []
        for root, _, files in walk(join(HOME, 'Desktop')):
            for file in files:
                filenames.append(join(root, file))
        ar = pool.map_async(process, filenames)
        master = concat(ar.get())
        print(master)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an IO bound task so multi-threading is the tool for the job. In python there are two ways to implement multi-threads. One using the `thread pool` and the second is using the `asyncio` that works with `event loop`. The `event loop` usually has better performance the challenge is to limit the number of threads executing at the same time. Fortunately, [Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483348/how-to-limit-concurrency-with-python-asyncio) wrote a very good solution for this.

This code creates an `event loop` that reads the files in several threads. The parameter `MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS` defines the amount of thread can execute at the same time. Try to play with this number for better performance as it is affected by the machine that runs it.

```
import os
import asyncio


async def read_file(file_path: str) -> str:
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        return f.read()


async def gather_with_concurrency(n, *tasks):
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(n)

    async def sem_task(task):
        async with semaphore:
            return await task
    return await asyncio.gather(*(sem_task(task) for task in tasks))


MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 100
file_name = []
file_path = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk("Folder_5M"):
    for name in files:
        file_path.append(os.path.join(path, name))
        file_name.append(name)
count = len(file_name)

tasks = [read_file(file) for file in file_path]
asyncio.run(gather_with_concurrency(MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS, *tasks))
```