# Asyncio send multiple thousand requests

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to create a script that can send a lot of requests to a website in the range of 100000 to 1.000.000. I am trying to use asyncio and aiohttp to do so but somehow I can't figure how to do it. It seem that it is creating the task but not completing it and I am not very experimented with asyncio and aiohttp.

How does the code work? Well basically it start by asking how much threads I want and how the proxy type for the proxies, then it go to the `start_workers` function where it is supposed to create the tasks and start. It use `asyncio.semaphore` to limit it to 10.000 concurrent requests at a time but it doesn't seem to be working. Then when it call the check function, it send a requets to a website, handle the response and update the stats. But from what I see it isn't and that is why I am here today. To check how the checker is doing I made a function called console that is basically running in a while true: loop to check each 2 second the progress made and also there is another function called `count_requests_per_minute` that is supposed to check how much requests can be approximately made in a minute. See the code by yourself bellow:

```
import threading
import os
import time
import random
from queue import Queue
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import Tk
from colorama import Fore
from urllib.parse import quote
import asyncio
import aiohttp
stats_lock = asyncio.Lock()
stats = {
    'valid': 0,
    'invalid': 0,
    'twofa': 0,
    'error': 0,
    'total_checked': 0,
    'cpm': 0
}


async def check(data, proxy, stats_lock, stats, session):
    

    payload = {
        'data':data
    }

    headers2 = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    }
    async with session.post("https://example_website.com", headers=headers2, data=payload, proxy=proxy) as response:
        response_text = await response.text()
        if "true" in response_text:
            stats['valid'] +=1
        elif "false" in response_text:
            stats['invalid']+=1


async def handler(data, proxy, proxytype, stats_lock, stats, session):
    async with session:
        proxy_url = f"http://{proxy}"
        await check(data, proxy_url, stats_lock, stats, session)


async def start_workers(threads, data_queue, proxies_list, proxies_input):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(threads)

    console_thread = threading.Thread(target=console, args=(len(data_queue),))
    console_thread.start()
    
    cpm_thread = threading.Thread(target=count_requests_per_minute) 
    cpm_thread.start()

    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(), trust_env=True) as session:
        for data in data_queue:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(handler(data, random.choice(proxies_list), proxies_input, stats_lock, stats, session))
            tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.sleep(0)  
            async with sem:
                await task

async def main():
    data_queue = []

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    threads = int(input(f"{Fore.RED}[{Fore.WHITE}?{Fore.RED}]{Fore.WHITE} - {Fore.RED}How many threads {Fore.WHITE}:{Fore.RED}"))

    proxies_input = input(f"\n{Fore.RED}[{Fore.WHITE}!{Fore.RED}]{Fore.WHITE} > {Fore.RED}Proxies type {Fore.WHITE}| {Fore.RED}HTTP{Fore.WHITE}/{Fore.RED}SOCKS4{Fore.WHITE}/{Fore.RED}SOCKS5 {Fore.WHITE}:{Fore.RED} ")

    combo_file = askopenfilename(title="Data File", parent=root)
    with open(combo_file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as combofile:
        data_queue.extend(combofile.read().splitlines())

    proxy_file = askopenfilename(title="Proxy File")
    with open(proxy_file, "r") as proxyfile:
        proxies_list = [line.strip() for line in proxyfile]

    await start_workers(threads, data_queue, proxies_list, proxies_input)


def count_requests_per_minute():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        stats['cpm'] = stats['total_checked'] * 60
        stats['total_checked'] = 0


def console(combo):
    print(f"\n{Fore.RED}[{Fore.WHITE}!{Fore.RED}]{Fore.WHITE} - {Fore.RED}Please wait while the console is loading.")
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system("cls")
    while True:
        os.system("cls")
        print(f"""
{Fore.RED}[{Fore.WHITE}Valid{Fore.RED}]{Fore.WHITE} | {Fore.RED}{stats['valid']}

{Fore.RED}[{Fore.WHITE}Invalid{Fore.RED}]{Fore.WHITE} | {Fore.RED}{stats['invalid']}

{Fore.RED}[{Fore.WHITE}Errors{Fore.RED}]{Fore.WHITE} | {Fore.RED}{stats['error']}

{Fore.RED}[{Fore.WHITE}Checked{Fore.RED}]{Fore.WHITE} | {Fore.RED}{stats['valid']+stats['invalid']}/{combo}

{Fore.RED}[{Fore.WHITE}CPM{Fore.RED}]{Fore.WHITE} | {Fore.RED}{stats['cpm']}
""")
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system("cls")
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except RuntimeError as e:
        if str(e) != "Event loop is closed":
            raise e  
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for data in data_queue:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(handler(data, random.choice(proxies_list), proxies_input, stats_lock, stats, session))
            tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.sleep(0)  
            async with sem:
                await task
```

Let me break this down for you:

1. Create a task and schedule it to run in the event loop (should really use `asyncio.create_task()` though).
2. Add the task to a list.
3. Yield to the event loop, at which point the task will be started before returning to this function.
4. Grab the semaphore. This has a limit of 10,000 and we are the only code using it, so it's at 1/10000.
5. *Wait for the task to complete.*
6. Release the semaphore, so we are back to 0/10000.
7. Repeat from step 1.

I hope it's pretty obvious from there, that you are running the tasks one at a time, thus defeating the point of using asyncio.

Instead, we can do:

```
await asyncio.gather(*(handler(d, ...) for d in data_queue))
```

Or, if you want something a little more dynamic:

```
async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
    for data in data_queue:
        tg.create_task(handler(data, ...))
```

For the semaphore, the easiest option would be to put it inside the tasks, though this obviously increases memory usage as you'd be creating 100,000+ tasks upfront and then having 90+% wait.

A better option might be to refactor so that you create 10,000 tasks which pull the data from an `asyncio.Queue` and just dump all the data into that queue (and just have the tasks return when the queue is empty). Or, some other examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484593/3010334

---

Some other small recommendations:

- Don't use `threading` in your application. That code should be fine to run as a task, but if you do need to do significant blocking operations, try `asyncio.to_thread()`.
- Use `asyncio.run()` to start your application, instead of using the low-level APIs (which is probably the reason you're managing to get some RuntimeError that shouldn't be happening).

Answer (score 0):

I've a feeling that you may also hit a limitation. Every network connection you create takes up a source port number. Usually one doesn't `bind()` a client end socket to a port, the OS will pick one at random and do that for you; it's used to associated returning packets with the socket that you `connect()` to the server.

Note that there can be only 65536 ports (it's limited to 16 bits) and a lot of those are reserved for various thing. I'm pretty sure that if one attempts to have more than 65536 open network connections simultaneously some sort of error will be thrown.

That could end up serialising your attempts at lots of network connections. Whilst you may be coding for many concurrent connections, if the underlying libraries (e.g. the one that's running http for you) are silently handling such errors and retrying on your behalf, they will end up running up to the maximum number of source ports available and no more.

To have a lot of truly concurrent connections, one may need a fair few machines.

Comment: They said they wanted to limit it to 10,000 simultaneous connections. The problem is clearly that the code limits it to 1 as I already answered.

Comment: @SamBull, sure, but the OP starts off saying they want to get to 100,000 to 1,000,000 million concurrent connections, which is unlikely to succeed. I took the 10,000 limit to be an attempt to understand the problem in their code which you have adequately described. But it still won't scale to achieve 100,000 or 1,000,000 concurrent connections.

Comment: I think you misread, it doesn't say concurrent at the start.

Comment: @SamBull, I'm comfortable that the intention is concurrent connections, given the use of asynchronous IO and the explicit reference "to limit it to 10.000 concurrent requests at a time". Sequential connections wouldn't require such I/O facilities, and wouldn't be much of a test of a website either.

Comment: What I mean is that the question states they want to download 100k+ things with 10,000 concurrent connections, from what I've understood. We seem to have interpreted different things from the question, but I don't see anything suggesting they are trying to do 100k+ connections in parallel.