# Is there any simplest way to run number of python request asynchronously?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-requests, python-asyncio

There is an API `localhost:8000/api/postdatetime/`, which is responsible for changing the online status of the driver. Every time a driver hits the API and if the response sent back then the driver status will be online otherwise the driver status will be offline.

`Drivers need to give the response within every 10 seconds.` If there is no response from the driver then he/she will be marked as offline automatically.

Currently what I am doing is getting all the logged in drivers and hitting the above-mentioned API one driver at a time.

For the simulation purpose, I populated thousands of drivers. To maintain the online-offline of thousands of drivers using my approach will leave almost many drivers offline.

The code for my approach is as described below:

`online-offline.py`

```py
import requests
import random
import math
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

from ** import get_logged_in_driver_ids
from ** import Driver


def post_date_time():
    url = 'localhost:8000/api/postdatetime/'

    while True:
        # getting all logged in driver ids 
        logged_in_driver_ids = get_logged_in_driver_ids() 

        # filtering the driver who are logged in and storing their user id in the driver_query variable
        driver_query = Driver.objects.only('id', 'user_id').filter(id__in=logged_in_driver_ids).values('user_id')

        # storing the user id of driver in list
        driver_user_ids = [driver['user_id'] for driver in driver_query]

        # getting number of drivers who are supposed to hit the API
        drivers_subset_count = math.ceil(len(driver_user_ids)*(random.randint(75, 85)/100))

        # shuffle the driver ids list to randomize the driver id order
        random.shuffle(driver_user_ids)

        # getting the driver list of length drivers_subset_count
        required_drivers = driver_user_ids[:drivers_subset_count]

        for driver in required_drivers:
            token = Token.objects.only('key', 'user_id').get(user_id=driver)
            req_headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Token' + ' ' + str(token)
            }
            response = requests.post(url=url, headers=req_headers)
            print(response.text)



if __name == '__main__':
    post_date_time()
```

Is there any idea that I can post request the `localhost:8000/api/postdatetime/` API asynchronously and can handle about 2-3000 of drivers within 10 seconds?

I am really new at implementing async codes. I have read some articles on the `aiohttp`  library but got confused at the time of implementing it.

This `online-offline.py` will run for the whole time of the simulation.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: If I understand situation correctly and API is local, asynchronous approach won't help you. Please, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180506/1113207) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and the explanation. But what if I used the non-local API, and want to achieve the result. How can be this achieved? Or, What if I used the local APIs and want to achieve the simulation. How can be this possible? All I want to do is handle the 2-3000 API requests within the 10 seconds for an unlimited time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of non-local API `asyncio` can help you. To make requests asynchronously you have to:

- use special syntax (`async def`, `await` - [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) for details)
- make requests non-blocking way (so you can await them)
- use [asyncio.gather()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) of similar way to make multiple requests parallely"
- start event loop

While it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210102/1113207) to make `requests` library work with `asyncio` using threads it's easier and better to use already asyncio-compatible library like `aiohttp`.

Take a look at [code snippets here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172471/1113207) `*`: they contain examples of making multiple concurrent requests. Rewrite you code same way, it'll look like:

```
import asyncio


async def driver_request(driver):
    # ...
    # use aiohttp to make request with custom headers:
    # https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#custom-request-headers


async def post_date_time():
    # ...

    await asyncio.gather(*[
        driver_request(driver) 
        for driver 
        in required_drivers
    ])


asyncio.run(post_date_time())
```

Locally you won't see any effect by default, so to test it locally you have to make `localhost` send response with delay to emulate real-life network delay.

---

`*` In latest Python version event loop can be run with just [asyncio.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run)

Comment: Apology for the late response. Thank you very much for your clear explanation. :)